# Wrong formatting in comments in the new Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, stack-overflow-app

Links and code snippets have bad formatting in the new Stack Overflow Android app.

Here a screenshot showing the issue:

[image: screen on stack overflow new app]

While everithing is fine with the *old* StackExchange app:

[image: screen on stack exchange old app]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44043070/4131048) is the post of the screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report! This bug is fixed as of version 1.0.1 which is pushing out now.

I was trying to avoid using the full Html parser the SE app is using for comments, but my replacement code didn't handle tags within tags very gracefully. The SO app now uses the same comment display parsing as the SE app.